# How to make a selenium java project to runnable jar file which use testng xml

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am try build my selenium project with runnable jar file.

I have use below code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { LoginTest.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();       
    }
```

It do giving me Configuration Failures: 1  as below:-

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Above code is running my class only. I need to run testng.xml. I have no clue what I did wrong here

I also have tried with sh file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./shtry.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
        try {
         Process p = pb.start();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                System.out.println(line);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

It works fine in IDE even its running my testng.xml but after creating running jar it do not showing me anything on terminal

I have also tried with below code:-

```
  List<String> testFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    testFilesList.add("./testng.xml"); //test suite resides in the working directory's root folder
    **testng.setTestSuites(testFilesList);** //you can addd multiple suites either here by adding multiple files or include all suites needed in the testng.xml file 
    testng.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
    testng.addListener(htmlRep); 
    testng.run();
```

It works fine in IDE even its running my testng.xml but again nothing works

Comment: Please be kind to rewrite your question title. It's incomprehensible

Comment: I have made the changes. Thats the best I can do for now